# Learning Arrays, How can I find the value of an array and its number position

Tags: java, arrays

How can I find the value of an array and its number position using for Loop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prac{
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            int n, element, pos=0, i;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
            System.out.println("Enter array size [1-100]: ");
            n = sc.nextInt();
            
            int[] a = new int[100];
            System.out.println("Enter array elements: ");
            for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
                a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            
            System.out.println("Enter element to search: ");
            element=sc.nextInt();
             
            for (i=0; i<n; i++) { 
                if (a[i]==element) {
                    System.out.println(element+ " found at position "+ i+1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(element+"not found");
```

When I run this it gives me this output:Enter array size [1-100]:
3
Enter array elements:
1
2
3
Enter element to search:
3
3 found at position 21

What kind of solution should I do to fix this?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Does it do what you expect? If not, what did it do instead?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you create an array with size 100 instead of size `n`, the value lookup looks fine at first glance, what exactly are you having trouble with? Please provide your input / output / expected output.

Comment: Insert an example

Comment: Java is not C: declare variables where you need them, rather than at the top of the method. Don't reuse variables (like `i`), because you risk forgetting to reset their values.

Comment: Ah so your problem is that `i+1` in your `System.out.println()` is evaluated as `String` concatenation instead of as addition.

Comment: @AndyTurner When I enter array size like to 3 then input 1, 2, 3 then input 3, it says 3 found at position 21

Comment: @Zervis_ so, the problem is not where you've said "Here is my problem"?

Comment: @Zervis_ have you looked at the linked question? That's what happens here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is:

In the print command, when you write `i+1` it is string.

For example if `i = 5`, the output is `51`, but you mean an integer.

Thus write `(i+1)`, So:

```
System.out.println(element + " found at position "+ (i+1));
```

Second problem is that your second print command is out of for loop. so it run anyway. One of the solution is that you can use `boolean` variable.

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prac {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, element, pos = 0, i;
        boolean flag = false;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
        System.out.println("Enter array size [1-100]: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

       int[] a = new int[n];
       System.out.println("Enter array elements: ");
       for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
           a[i] = sc.nextInt();
       

       System.out.println("Enter element to search: ");
       element = sc.nextInt();

       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           if (a[i] == element) {
               System.out.println(element + " found at position " + (i+1));
               flag = true;
           }
       }
       if(!flag) // flag == false
           System.out.println(element + "not found");
   }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: This worked but it also says not found at the same time

Comment: @Zervis_ Because you're printing "not found" regardless of what happens. You need to fix your logic so that it is only printed if the number really wasn't found

Comment: Oh I forgot it is outside

Comment: @Zervis_ if this answer helped and fixed your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark.